# Loop Through Files to Find Specific Files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a macro where you can open certain files with a certain name without having to go through the files I have already filtered through.

In the code before this macro, it loops through an entire folder, and opens all of the files that meet a criteria, pull a number from there, pastes into the new workbook, closes that workbook, and goes to the next file.

I have the criteria in a range in the current workbook, and I want to use that criteria when determining which workbooks to open in the folder.

I'm wondering if there is a way to start looping through the folder starting with the last file that was opened using the macro before.

EDIT: The following code is what I have so far.

```
Sub LoopThroughFilesInFolder()

'=============================================================================
'Looping through all of the files in the folder, and grabbing the last value
'=============================================================================

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FolderPicker As FileDialog

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FolderPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FolderPicker
    .Title = "Select a Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In case of cancel
NextCode:
    MyPath = MyPath
    If MyPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension
myExtension = "*1*9 Restraint*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extension
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
i = LastRow - 1
Do While MyFile <> ""
    If MyFile Like Cells(LastRow, 1).Value Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & MyFile, ReadOnly:=True)
        'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on
        DoEvents

        'Find last row
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        'Grab value next to last row
        LastValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value
        If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(LastValue) = False Then
            LastValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 3).Value
        End If

        'Go back to graph workbook
        Workbooks("Workbook Name").Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(i, 2).Value = MyFile
        Workbooks("Workbook Name").Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(i, 3).Value = LastValue
        i = i + 1
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        DoEvents
        MyFile = Dir
    End If
Loop

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
ResetSettings:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

This is looping through the entire folder (there are about 1000 files). My question above assumes that we have already done this macro, and the macro I am trying to currently write will only open the most recent files matching a certain criteria, still from the same folder though (but without having to loop through the files that were already opened from the previous macro).

Comment: Probably. Please [edit] your question with the code you have so far, and it will be easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: If you've changed the criteria wouldn't you want to start again?

Comment: Wouldn't you just have a higher order `For` loop that will maintain your flow through the files in the folder..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dir$() without a new file pattern retrieves the next matching file (Win32 FindNextFile), whereas Dir$(file pattern) starts the search over again, even if the pattern is the same as the previous one (Win32 FindFirstFile).

That being said, maybe do something like

```
Static bolBeenHere As Boolean

If bolBeenHere = False Then
' First search, use the file search pattern
   ' Target Path with Ending Extension
   MyFile = Dir(MyPath & myExtension)
   bolBeenHere = True
Else
' Retrieve the next matching file
   MyFile = Dir$()
End If

' Stuff
Do While MyFile <> ""
...
Loop
```

A small performance advice. Use

```
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
```

instead of

```
Do While MyFile <> ""
```

A string comparison "costs" more than a numeric comparison.